# Roll Up Summary clarification?

Tags: roll-up-summary

I have created a rollup summary for `Account` in relation to `Opportunity` with the filter criteria:

> Stage EQUALS Negotiation/Review, Closed Won

The above criteria give perfect results, but when I change them to:

> (Stage EQUALS Negotiation/Review)  AND (Stage EQUALS Closed Won)

The above criteria yields `Null`. Why? This result seems incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two criteria you presented are different. The first one tries to find records which *Stage* field is one of the two options. The second one tries to find records which *Stage* field is both *Negotiation/Review* **AND** *Closed Won* at the same time, which won't happen.

You can use the second approach if you change the **AND** connector by **OR**.